# How to reference Easing Function in Xamarin Forms XAML (TouchView Library)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using a library called "TouchView" (https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/TouchEffect) for xamarin forms which enables you to generate animations that respond to touches in xaml. Here's an example of my xaml code:

```
<touch:TouchView x:Name="myView"
            PressedAnimationDuration="25"
            RegularAnimationDuration="600"
            RippleCount="0"
            Padding="10, 5"
            RegularBackgroundColor="White"
            PressedBackgroundColor="Red"
             StateChanged="Handle_StateChanged"
            Completed="Handle_TouchCompleted">

            <Label Text="P5" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   FontSize="60"/>

        </touch:TouchView>
```

However, the TouchView class also defines two properties PressedAnimationEasing and RegularAnimationEasing that are of type Xamarin.Forms.Easing. In the code behind I have:

```
this.myView.RegularAnimationEasing = Easing.CubicOut;
```

However, I'd like to assign this easing function in xaml because I want the views to go in a data template. When I try this:

```
<touch:TouchView x:Name="myView"
            RegularAnimationEasing = "CubicOut"
</touch:TouchView>
```

...it generates the following error: Cannot assign property "RegularAnimationEasing": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property.

Is it possible to assign an Easing Function in XAML and how do you do it?

Comment: Is not possible to use animations directly on xaml (read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter22) ), maybe you can create a behavior that triggers the animation and attach to your template.

Comment: Well I was aware of that. However, the animations are being triggered by the library indeed in C# code. This is not a question of how to trigger the animation but simply: How do I assign a value of type Xamarin.Forms.Easing to a public property on an object in XAML?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the x:Static markup extension to assign Easing from XAML:

```
<touch:TouchView x:Name="myView"
                 RegularAnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicOut}" />
```